# Can you instantiate a bunch of objects really fast in VrChat?

Tags: unity

I want to know if you can instantiate objects as fast as an avatar can run. I want to create a path of objects based on a path that a player has drawn that an avatar can run on. To do that, I want it use instantiate on an array of prefabs to make the path. I can’t find, however, whether VrChat can handle spawning at that speed. Does anyone know if that is possible? Or, at least, how I can find out if that is possible?

Comment: This looks like a question that's best answered by trying it. So: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing yet. I just went through a fire and haven’t gotten my laptop back yet.